# Try, except, and finally statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

So I am developing a nitro type bot and I don't see a reason I should be getting an error but around 20 races in it is going directly to sending me an email. Am I use the statements wrong or what I am new to python so if it is really simple and a dumb mistake plz be nice and if it is something you could easily find on the web im really sorry.

```
        try:
            time.sleep(4)
            driver.get('https://www.nitrotype.com/garage')
            driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn--light:nth-child(2)').click()
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn--primary').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.dash-copyContainer')
            time.sleep(4.25)
            html = driver.page_source.replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
            f = open("word.html", "w")
            f.write(html)
            f.close()

            with open("word.html", "r") as html_file:
                content = html_file.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
            words = soup.find_all('span', class_='dash-letter')
            stuff = ""
            for span in words:
                if span.text.isascii():
                    stuff += span.text
            with open("Sentence.txt", "w") as wf:
                 wf.write(stuff)
            wf.close()

            e = open('Sentence.txt', 'r')
            s = e.read()
            Words = (s.split())
            Delay = ((len(s.split()) / WPM) * 60)
            int(Delay)
            Delay1 = Delay / len(s.split())
            for Word in Words:
                pyautogui.typewrite(Word + " ")
                time.sleep(Delay1)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.get('https://www.nitrotype.com/garage')
        except:
            time.sleep(4)
            driver.get('https://www.nitrotype.com/garage')
            driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn--light:nth-child(2)').click()
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn--primary').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.dash-copyContainer')
            time.sleep(4.25)
            html = driver.page_source.replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
            f = open("word.html", "w")
            f.write(html)
            f.close()

            with open("word.html", "r") as html_file:
                content = html_file.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
            words = soup.find_all('span', class_='dash-letter')
            stuff = ""
            for span in words:
                if span.text.isascii():
                    stuff += span.text
            with open("Sentence.txt", "w") as wf:
                wf.write(stuff)
            wf.close()

            e = open('Sentence.txt', 'r')
            s = e.read()
            Words = (s.split())
            Delay = ((len(s.split()) / WPM) * 60)
            int(Delay)
            Delay1 = Delay / len(s.split())
            for Word in Words:
                pyautogui.typewrite(Word + " ")
                time.sleep(Delay1)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.get('https://www.nitrotype.com/garage')
        finally:
            driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Braeden/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
            driver1.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')
            time.sleep(2)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('#identifierId')\
                .send_keys(EU)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('.VfPpkd-vQzf8d').click()
            time.sleep(2)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('<div class="VfPpkd-RLmnJb"></div>')\
                .send_keys(EP)
            time.sleep(1)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ > span:nth-child(2)').click()
            time.sleep(2)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ > div:nth-child(1)').click()
            time.sleep(2)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('.T-I-KE').click()
            time.sleep(2)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('#\:c1')\
                .send_keys(TO)
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('#\:co')\
                .send_keys('Nitro type requires Captcha')
            driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('#\:b9').click()
            driver1.close()
            input('Did you complete the captcha:')
```

Comment: It is generally bad practice to have bare exceptions. It would be a good idea to have a specific type of exception in mind when using it, for exmple ```Except ValueError:```. Also, ```finally``` run regardless of the success of the try/except. I didn't look at the rest of your code to find a specific error.

Comment: So like what would i do if when i get an error with the try just repeat it because sometimes nitro type has a server error and i need it to refresh the page if that happens

Comment: You could have it in a for or while loop (for is probably better to avoid infinite loops). ```for i in range(5): try: YOUR CODE break except YOUR CHOICE OF EXCEPTION: pass``` This will try at most 5 times.